# Convert an immutable array of objects into mutable in react state

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array containing objects in javascript / typescript.

```
let array = [
            { id: 1, name: "One", location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } },
            { id: 2, name: "Two", location: { lat: 23.2226, lng: 56.2214 } },
            { id: 3, name: "Three", location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } },
          ];
```

How can I update location of the second element (with lat 23.2226) and copy the array to a new array using javascript spread (...) operator?

Comment: Please give us more information!

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [
             { id: 1, name: "One", location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } },
             { id: 2, name: "Two", location: { lat: 23.2226, lng: 56.2214 } },
             { id: 3, name: "Three", location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } },
           ];

array.find((d) => (d['name'] == 'Two'))['location']['lat'] = 23.000

console.log(array)
/*[
  { id: 1, name: 'One', location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } },
  { id: 2, name: 'Two', location: { lat: 23, lng: 56.2214 } },
  { id: 3, name: 'Three', location: { lat: 23.2223, lng: 56.2214 } }
]*/
```